# Postfix regexp header_check for endif shows ERROR: expected format: key whitespace value

Tags: postfix-mta

I'm using the postfix version **3.5.9**
in main.cf

```
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

in /etc/postfix/header_checks

```
if /^From:/
!/(^From:.*domain\.com|^From:.*domain\.net|^From:.*domain\.co\.il)/ REJECT SEND FROM THE RIGHT DOMAINS FFS!
endif
```

However, when I use `postmap /etc/postfix/header_checks`, it occurs error: `postmap: warning: /etc/postfix/header_checks, line 3: expected format: key whitespace value`

I don't understand why and how to fix it. does someone have ideas on it?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a postfix bug. Not critical.
It's just that the postmap validator looks for strings that should have the format: "key whitespace value". The first two lines in your example is ok. But the third is not. I added a **space** and a **comment character** after the completion of the condition (**endif**). In your case it will be like this:

```
if /^From:/
    !/(^From:.*domain\.com|^From:.*domain\.net|^From:.*domain\.co\.il)/ REJECT SEND FROM THE RIGHT DOMAINS FFS!
endif #
```